# GDB: address relative to shared library

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, shared-libraries

I am debugging a program which refuses to work in our custom linux environment. I have no access to its sources, thus cannot compile or add anything.
The issue is somewhere in one of its shared libraries, and I know the approximate address range (and nothing else). The question is: how do I set breakpoint on the location without manual labour like

```
info sharedlibrary
<find address of library.so>
break <address of library.so>+<location>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The question is: how do I set breakpoint on the location without manual labour like

GDB (by default) disables address randomization.

If you run the program under GDB from the start (i.e. not `attach` already running process), then you should only need to perform the "manual labour" once, and reuse the same address on all subsequent runs.

**Update:**

> I can't run the app under GDB from the start. I can't start it manually.

In that case, just disable ASLR system-wide (while you are debugging):

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I can't run the app under GDB from the start. I can't start it manually.